# What's the simplest way to create a Inspector view with disclosure triangles for different sections?

Tags: macos, cocoa, user-interface

Is there a more simple way of doing this that creating a view based outline view? (I'm working on an application for OS X)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using an `NSOutlineView` is almost certainly *not* the approach to take.

---

Apple provide the disclosure triangle as a button in Interface Builder's *Object Library*, so this is the first bit of the puzzle.

[image]

They also provide an `NSStackView` within the same library:

[image]

This class was introduced recently, and the [demo](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/InfoBarStackView/Introduction/Intro.html) Apple have provided to showcase it is - serendipitously for you - a rudimentary Inspector-type view:

[image]

With the button, the stack view, and this demo, you should be able to put together whatever it is you're after.

Answer (score 1):

I found this tutorial to be supremely helpful: http://jpopham.github.io/01-sidebar-swift-OSX/